# Can anyone figure out why the integer of this VBA script stops increasing?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on the following code:

```
Sub RemoveNumber()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    While i <= 20000

        Set Rng = Range("A" & i)
        If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True Then
            Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = False Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Essentially, it loops through a column and removes cells with numbers. This much works well, but the loop doesn't end. Further testing by inserting `Range("B2").value = i` shows that when i reaches 18450 (the first empty cell in the column), i stops increasing. But surely and empty cell should trigger the `Else` statement at the end, right?

Comment: Blank cells return a `TRUE` result for the `IsNumeric` method.  So basically, it just keeps deleting the blank cell over and over.

Comment: So essentially you'll need to change your initial `If` line to be: `If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True And Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Interesting. That was my first impression, but using `IsNumber` on the suspect cell gave me a `False` statement. Will do further testing. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the worksheetfunction `=ISNUMBER` is *not* the same as the VBA method `IsNumeric`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will miss rows.  As it deletes rng the next is moved up and then it moves to the next row.  If there are back to back number values it will skip every other one.

One good method to avoid all this is to loop backwards:

```
Sub RemoveNumber()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
For i = 20000 To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = Range("A" & i)
    If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) And Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True` is redundant and could be simplified to `IsNumeric(Rng.Value)`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug that is correct.  I copied and pasted and did not think about that as I was more concerned about the method of the loop.  Thanks.  I corrected it.

Comment: Are you sure the script will skip based on how I've written it? If Rng is numeric, the cell is deleted and the one beneath it is shifted up. But the integer i doesn't increase under this condition, and Rng stays the same, checking if the new cell is numeric too. The integer only increases if Rng is not numeric.

Comment: No you are correct I missed it.  But why do extra loops or code when not needed?